# DB2 how to prevent to delete values (with 'before delete' trigger)?

Tags: db2

I have code like this:

```
CREATE TABLE A10.STUDENTS
( IDSTUDENT INTEGER NOT NULL,
LASTNAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
MARK DECIMAL(5,1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ( IDSTUDENT )
);

ALTER TABLE A10.STUDENTS ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK_MARK CHECK(CAST(MARK AS DECIMAL(5,1)) IN (2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0));

INSERT INTO A10.STUDENTS (LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,MARK) VALUES ('Smith','John',2.0);
```

and I want to add "before delete" trigger, that prevent deleting marks under 3.0.

```
-- <ScriptOptions statementTerminator="@" />
CREATE TRIGGER A10.DONT_DELETE_MARKS
NO CASCADE BEFORE DELETE
ON A10.STUDENTS
REFERENCING NEW AS N OLD AS O
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL NOT SECURED
BEGIN 
    --and what here?
END@
-- <ScriptOptions statementTerminator=";" />
```

I have tried something like:

```
raise_application_error(-20001,'Records can not be deleted');
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Please, show what you have tried exactly so far. What's the error or unexpected result you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does "doesn't work" mean?

What platform and version of Db2?

Try

```
signal sqlstate xxxxx
   set message_text = 'Records can not be deleted';
```

replace `xxxxx` with the SQL Statecode you wish to use.  Note that

> SQLSTATE values are comprised of a two-character class code value,
> followed by a three-character subclass code value. Class code values
> represent classes of successful and unsuccessful completion
> conditions. If you want to use SQLSTATE as the basis of your
> application's return codes, you can define your own SQLSTATE classes
> or subclasses using the following guidelines:
>
> - SQLSTATE classes that begin with the characters 7 through 9 or I through Z can be defined. Within these classes, any subclass can be
>   defined.
> - SQLSTATE classes that begin with the characters 0 through 6 or A through H are reserved for the database manager. Within these classes,
>   subclasses that begin with the characters 0 through H are reserved for
>   the database manager. Subclasses that begin with the characters I
>   through Z can be defined.

Comment: Yeah, I'm new to DB2, so sorry for my disorientation. Version is DB2 Express-C v11.1.4040.491.
Your answer really helped me (and also with DB2 Cookbook) I managed to solve it.